# How can a smallfiles setting for journaling save disk space?

Tags: mongodb

We are going to upgrade to mongdb 2.4.6 server with in a week .
I am really worried about the default **journaling** option set to true on 64 bit machines  considering the size of the **journal** files would be created (as our application is  more of write bound) .

My question is that even though i enable **smallfiles = true** option , how really this can reduce the disk space ( As in my view instead of a 1 GB journal  file , it wil create equavalent  many 128 bytes small journal  files )

Is it that this **smallfiles=true** is only applicable only  during mongo server start up ?? and nothing related to saving of disk space ??

Please let me know if i myunderstaning is wrong , or else please how a smallfiles setting true will help ??

Comment: The journal file is only ever so big, if you plan on using a database I would strongly suggest you don't turn off journaling. smallfiles basically stops all pre-alloc including performance pre-alloc

Comment: @Sammaye , could you please tell me what do you mean by this statement  "The journal file is only ever so big, if you plan on using a database" ?? is  it that journal file can be used on other things also in mongodb ??